# Setting a log file name to current time up to seconds but generating a log every hour in Log4j

Tags: log4j, appender

I would like to generate a log file every hour but its name should be appended with date and time up to seconds.

Eg of a log name :

Testlog.log_13.07.11_12.33.40.log

I have included the following code in appender :

param name="DatePattern" value="'*'yy.MM.dd'*'HH.mm.ss'.log'"/

But this generates a log file every second.

Is there anyway to generate logs every hour?